# MVC Error using Lists and Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new to this and am doing a little project to get to know how it all works.

So I'm looking to create a header image area on each page by placing the code in the "_Layout.cshtml" file and attempting to control what image displays according to "ViewBag.Title".

I have broken the code up into the pages, followed by a pic. of the error. I just can't work out what the problem is.

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebSite_Project_1.Controllers
{
public partial class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    [ActionName("Funny-Bones")]
    public ActionResult FunnyBones()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "This is funny bones.";

        return View();
    }
    public class Headers
    {
        public string HeaderName { get; set; }
        public string PageName { get; set; }
        public int HeaderWidth { get; set; }
        public int HeaderHeight { get; set; }
        public string HeaderType { get; set; }
    }
    public ActionResult HeaderImages()
    {
            var model = new List<Headers>();

            model.Add(new Headers { HeaderName = "home", PageName = "Home Page", HeaderWidth = 2200, HeaderHeight = 1172, HeaderType = ".png" });
            model.Add(new Headers { HeaderName = "about", PageName = "About", HeaderWidth = 2200, HeaderHeight = 1172, HeaderType = ".png" });
            model.Add(new Headers { HeaderName = "contact", PageName = "Contact", HeaderWidth = 2200, HeaderHeight = 1172, HeaderType = ".png" });
            model.Add(new Headers { HeaderName = "funnybones", PageName = "Funny Bones", HeaderWidth = 2200, HeaderHeight = 1172, HeaderType = ".png" });

            return View(model);
    }
}
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<WebSite_Project_1.Controllers.HomeController.Headers>

<div class="headersImage">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (@item.PageName == @ViewBag.Title)
            {
                <img src="~/Content/Images/@item.HeaderName+@item.HeaderType" title="@item.HeaderName" />
            }
        }
</div>
@RenderBody()
```

The problem starts when I try and publish it and then i get this error pointing to Model in the "foreach" loop.

I'm not a 100% sure the loop is right, but haven't been able to get that far yet.

[Link to MVC error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5eZk.png)

Comment: this usage is not suggested way, you should define your model class in model folder and then create List instance of it by importing WebSite_Project_1.Models namespace

Comment: You should post the error as text instead of an image so others with the same error can find it using search engines.

Comment: then change this line IEnumerable<WebSite_Project_1.Controllers.HomeController.Headers> with IEnumerable<WebSite_Project_1.Models.Headers> and write your foreach code in HeaderImages view instead of layout to dont get NullExeption

Comment: Hi hsnbl,I changed that line to your suggestion and a red squiggly line appeared under Models. And that's with me creating a new file in 'Shared' called HeaderImages.cshtml and putting a line in _Layout.cshtml in its place to pull it in which is @RenderPage("HeaderImages.cshtml")

Comment: When I roll over Models with the red squiggly line I get the following message, and again I'm really new to this so I'm not fully getting it. The type or namespace name 'Models' does not exist in namespace 'Website_Project_1' (are you missing an assembly reference)

Comment: @LeeJones you can use RenderBody() in your layout after your action worked it redirect to its view, the view will be rendered in layout.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

You should *never* specify a model for a layout. The model passed in will always be the one for the view, which almost invariably, will *not* be the same one the layout is wanting.

For things like this, you should use child actions. Essentially, just take your existing `HeaderImages` action, add the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute (which prevents it from being routed to directly), and change the return to:

```
return PartialView("_HeaderImages", model);
```

You can call the view whatever you want, but essentially it would just have the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebSite_Project_1.Controllers.HomeController.Headers>

<div class="headersImage">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (@item.PageName == @ViewBag.Title)
        {
            <img src="~/Content/Images/@item.HeaderName+@item.HeaderType" title="@item.HeaderName" />
        }
    }
</div>
```

Finally, in your layout, remove the model definition line and replace the header image code currently there with:

```
@Html.Action("HeaderImages", "Home")
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I missed one thing. The child action will render in a separate context from the main view/layout (that's sort of the point). However, that means it has its own `ViewBag`, so you can't access the `ViewBag` from the main action directly. Instead, you'll need to pass it in as a route value:

```
@Html.Action("HeaderImages", "Home", new { title = ViewBag.Title })
```

Then, modify your child action to accept this param, and set *its* `ViewBag`:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult HeaderImages(string title)
{
    ...
    ViewBag.Title = title;
    return PartialView("_HeaderImages", model);
}
```